# virtualize or bypass EPT support in Vmware Esxi

Tags: vmware-esxi

I am trying to run a VM that requires EPT support, which my cpu(X7350) appears to not support.(Enabling hardware MMU creates an error saying that host does not support EPT).

When I run that VM i get the following error

> Virtualized msg.intel.hvhwmmu requires a preferred mode of
>   msg.intel.hvhwmmu.

Is there a way to bypass that requirement or do EPT in software?

Comment: What's "*EPT*"?

Comment: Extended Page Table

Comment: Does [this knowledge base article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=1036775&sliceId=1&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&dialogID=518936805&stateId=0%200%20518946538) help you out?

Comment: What version of ESXi?